# Move to Italy having an Hungarian student visa

Tags: schengen

I am a coach in a basketball team, and we would like to sign a Nigerian player (underage) currently playing in Hungary. Can he move to Italy having a Hungarian student visa?

Comment: His student visa should allow him to apply for the necessary Italian visa *in Hungary,* but as noted in o.m.'s [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14593/2440), it does not allow him to move to Italy or to work there.  Italy might allow him to travel to Italy with the Hungarian visa and (within 90 days) apply directly for a residence permit.  I don't know whether this is the case; the countries I *am* familiar with don't generally permit this, so it seems unlikely.

Comment: No, we had already issues with immigration office in the past trying to obtain a student visa for extra-EU players while the 90 days of permitted stay. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. With a national (D) visa he can **visit** Italy or other Schengen countries for up to 90 days out of every 180 days, but he cannot permanently move there and he may not work in Italy, either.

For moving permanently, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.